Use fallback language in language selector
Pretty new to Sitecore and FED in general. I'm currently trying to solve the following bug that we have:
We have a LanguageSelector component and the website's default language is English. When we select a language from the dropdown of which the XM Cloud has no content we get redirected to the 404 Page not found page. Instead, we want to have the English fallback language.
I feel that I should somehow check if we get a 404 page not found error when a different language is chosen hence the const checkContentAvailiblity, but I'm stuck on how to proceed further.
Is someone able to help out or point me in a different direction? Would be greatly appreciated! Any tips or pointers are welcome!

Is language fallback enabled on your instance?

Hi @RichardSeal thanks for replying! This morning I indeed found the XM documentation for fallback language and this was configured/setup properly. Our React project also has a EnableLanguageFallback.config. Snippet:    
<patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
<patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>


<patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
<patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>

So today it got solved! Turns out it shouldn't have been a bug at all... The fallback language was correctly implemented, however the testers just didn't publish it properly.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/language-fallback-and-publishing.html
When you publish fallback language versions for the first time, you must publish each version to ensure that they are saved on Edge.
